# core data to many sorting on fetch

Tags: core-data

I have a many to many and would like to sort this so that (Event)title is the keyPath listing associated (Person)name below, including duplicates when is the case.  something like this.

data model description
Event <<---->> Person, inverse relationships are 'events' and 'people' each with a single attribute eventTitle and personName.

eventTitle1
personNameA
personNameB
eventTitle2
personNameA
personNameC

I've worked with to-one fetchRequests and sorted on keyPath with sortDescriptors. what needs to be done differently for the to many to work this way.  Is that enough information?  First post, any/ all assistance very appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to fetch "event" entities and sort them according to their eventTitle attribute. So you would set up your sort descriptors for those entities the same as you would for your to-one fetches, since eventTitle is a to-one attribute. You'd then access the "person" entities through the retrieved "event" entities. That doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks Wienke! Yes that is exactly what I want to do to use with the provided table view methods for display. I'm not seeing how to do the last part within the frc, been trying a couple things and it's not working for me. Can you give me a little more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would get the fetch request to get the "Person" entity, and sort by event then person. Sort of like this.

```
NSSortDescriptor *eventSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"event.name" 
                                                                     ascending:ascending 
                                                                      selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSSortDescriptor *personSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"
                                                                    ascending:ascending 
                                                                     selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:eventSortDescriptor, personSortDescriptor, nil];


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                            managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
                                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:@"event.name"
                                                                                                       cacheName:cacheName];
```

Comment: has given you the right answer. I was forgetting that NSFetchRequest would let you sort on multiple levels at once -- that's why it takes an array of sort descriptors instead of just one.